# How to determine if returned Json is a simple string or encoded object - jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

Is there a way to determine if the controller is sending back a simple Json string, or an encoded object?

If the information is returned correctly it will be sent as an encoded object...

```
Return Json(vResult, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
```

But is there is an exception a simple string...

```
Return Json(UnhandledError)
```

How can I check to see which is being returned?

Something like this

```
success: function (response) {
if (response is Json object) { // This is the problem bit
                $('#textareaDescription').val(response.Description);  
            }
            else {
              ModalError(response);


            }
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            ModalError(textStatus + " - " + errorThrown);
        }
```

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean a "simple string"?  Depending on what you mean by that, and how your ajax is written, if you are returning a non-json response to an ajax request that expects a json response, it could encounter an error when it tries to parse it.

Comment: But on a side note, imho, if you are returning data related to an "unhandled error", hopefully you would also be returning a non-2xx response code as well

Comment: Simple string like Return Json("<p>There was an error blah, blah</p>")

Comment: how does `Json()` encode that string as json?  does it put it in an array?  because on it's own, that is not json.

Comment: No need for a response code as that is emailed separately- just a user notification Modal with a generic message. I can filter a returned string with indexOf but that will throw an error if its object Object

Comment: One is a string, the other is an object like this Dim vResult = New With {Key .Description = vDescription, .ContName = vContName, .ContAddress = vContAddress, .ContLicence = vContLicence,
                    .ContPhone = vContPhone, .Ref1 = vRef1, .Ref2 = vRef2, .Ref3 = vRef3, .IsPostContruct = vIsPostConstruct, .IsContractor = vIsContractor,
                    .IsHarmless = vIsHarmless, .IsMaintain = vIsMaintain}
                Return Json(vResult, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)

Comment: I'm asking for the case that you are returning the error message, what is the actual content on the response that the browser is receiving?  You can see this by looking in your developer tools at the network request and looking at the response tab

Comment: I have added a bit more to the question

Comment: Does `Return Json("I got a string here")` return on the response just `"I got a string here"` or does it manipulate it some how?  I'm not an asp developer and am unfamiliar with how `Json()` will process a string for the response.  That's why I'm asking for clarification.  I understand that it should take an object and convert it into the json format of an object with key value pairs, but it is unclear to me how it will manipulate input that cannot be associated with json naturally.

Comment: If it sends anything else then jQuery handles that and I can just interrogate it as a string - but string methods won't work if it's an encoded object and vice versa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After talking with you in the comments, it appears that the ajax automatically parsing the response in the good case.  I'm assuming that in the bad case it is not attempting to parse it, otherwise it would encounter an error before it got into your success handler.

This could be the case if the service endpoint, for the good case, is setting the Content-Type on the response to json so that jQuery knows to auto parse it for you.  In any case, you can use that to your advantage.

```js
if (typeof response === 'string') {
  //do logic for bad response
} else {
  //do logic for good response
}
```

Or you could potentially flip it and check for the typeof to be 'object'.

Comment: When it's sending the encoded object it hits 'SyntaxError: Invalid character' when parsing

Comment: Try putting `console.log(typeof test)` in your logic immediately before the parse.  Replacing `test` with your response variable (of course, :P)

Comment: It returned 'object'

Comment: Aaaaah, ok, and what does it return in the error case? (I'm guessing it's going to print 'string')

Comment: However if (typeof (response) == 'object') {
                    alert('This is an object');
                } seems to work

Comment: Yup - so running if - else it catches the object and works and likewise for the string - if you want to amend you answer (you got me onto typeof) I can mark it up